# Setting Progress Bar Value inside a list view with <%# Eval("") %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've hit a wall with my asp.net learning. I've been trying to code a Progress Bar within a list view. Problem is that the way I control the progress bar is inline through the  like as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td><%# Eval("TransactionNumber") %></td>
    <td>
        <div class="progress">
              <div ID="pbJobOrder" style="width: <%# Eval("ProgressBarVal")%>%;" runat="server" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar orange medium-progress">
              </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to bind data like this because it will appear in a list view. I can't do this because it's telling me it's not a valid value for the width property.. Help!

Comment: how does your output html look like?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply, but here is an example of how it'll look like in the list view [link](http://imgur.com/z5acDXN)